# How to remove the label from geom_label_repel() in the third facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have the following data frame:

```
    structure(list(levels = c("Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", 
"High", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", 
"Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High", 
"Low", "Medium", "High", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", ""), days = c(3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 5.2, 5.2, 5.2, 5.9, 5.9, 
5.9, 7, 7, 7, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 5.2, 5.2, 5.2, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 7, 
7, 7, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 5.2, 5.2, 5.2, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 7, 7, 7), 
    categories = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
    "0.5", "1"), class = "factor"), fit = c(0.006681428, 0.006604253, 
    0.006527963, 0.010609297, 0.005799118, 0.003162868, 0.012692178, 
    0.00551306, 0.002384881, 0.016807205, 0.005091636, 0.001529772, 
    0.0125202, 0.009006417, 0.00647231, 0.014553106, 0.00902407, 
    0.005583731, 0.015428702, 0.009030945, 0.005271914, 0.016910442, 
    0.009041758, 0.004816553, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), se = c(0.004542971, 0.001805012, 0.00480149, 
    0.00471013, 0.001326741, 0.001551987, 0.004750372, 0.001205801, 
    0.001008321, 0.005366604, 0.001086265, 0.000581074, 0.004243848, 
    0.001786382, 0.00233388, 0.003867866, 0.001699203, 0.001569163, 
    0.00382492, 0.001681837, 0.001383752, 0.004003663, 0.001674544, 
    0.001219947, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), lower = c(0.00175533, 0.003862174, 0.001537301, 0.004430336, 
    0.003701695, 0.001207622, 0.00607794, 0.003589446, 0.001040653, 
    0.00896413, 0.003350344, 0.000726369, 0.006428368, 0.006101782, 
    0.003188264, 0.008629558, 0.006235693, 0.003216664, 0.009475882, 
    0.006265836, 0.003149848, 0.010615311, 0.006286038, 0.00293036, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), upper = c(0.025084575, 
    0.011271135, 0.027277596, 0.025187986, 0.009074141, 0.008257659, 
    0.026313711, 0.008458803, 0.00545599, 0.031295798, 0.007730918, 
    0.003218919, 0.024244082, 0.013275278, 0.013094624, 0.024442476, 
    0.013042945, 0.009675756, 0.025026645, 0.013000329, 0.008810988, 
    0.026837471, 0.012989758, 0.007907206, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), time = c("1 day", "1 day", "1 day", 
    "2 days", "2 days", "2 days", "3 days", "3 days", "3 days", 
    "4 days", "4 days", "4 days", "1 day", "1 day", "1 day", 
    "2 days", "2 days", "2 days", "3 days", "3 days", "3 days", 
    "4 days", "4 days", "4 days", "1 day", "1 day", "1 day", 
    "2 days", "2 days", "2 days", "3 days", "3 days", "3 days", 
    "4 days", "4 days", "4 days"), time_labels = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1 day", "2 days", "3 days", 
    "4 days"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I created the following ggplot:

```
e.df$time_labels <- factor(e.df$time, levels=c("1 day", "2 days", "3 days", "4 days"))

e.df$categories <- as.factor(e.df$categories)

xy_labs <- e.df %>%
  group_by(levels) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(pos = which.max(time_labels),
            x = time_labels[pos],
            y = fit[pos]) %>%
  filter(!is.na(y))

g2 <- ggplot(e.df,aes(x=time,y=fit,color=levels,ymin=lower,ymax=upper)) +  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+ geom_line(aes(group = levels), linetype = "dotted") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),  width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_label_repel(data=xy_labs, aes(x=x, y=y, label = levels, color = levels), 
                   nudge_x = 0.1, inherit.aes=F, 
                   na.rm = FALSE) + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none") + facet_wrap(~ categories) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#0072B2", "#CC79A7", "#cacaca")) + ylim(0, 0.045) 

plot(g2)
```

I end up with a graph that has labels on the third facet (categories == 1). How do I remove those labels? I want a blank graph for the third facet. Eventually, I want to be able to show the lines one at a time. I'm creating this for a presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want labels per facet it looks more appropriate to me to include `categories` in the `group_by` when creating the labels dataset. This way the labels are placed at the correct position and as a side-effect that will automatically remove the labels from the third panel:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

xy_labs <- e.df %>%
  group_by(levels, categories) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    pos = which.max(time_labels),
    x = time_labels[pos],
    y = fit[pos]
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(y))

ggplot(e.df, aes(x = time, y = fit, color = levels, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = levels), linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
    width = 0.2,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = xy_labs, aes(x = x, y = y, label = levels, color = levels),
    nudge_x = 0.1, inherit.aes = F,
    na.rm = FALSE
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~categories) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#0072B2", "#CC79A7", "#cacaca")) +
  ylim(0, 0.045)
```

[image]